# Переброс вопроса с одного аккаунта на другой

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено

Не мог зайти в аккаунт на SO несколько дней (посредством ВК). В результате пришлось воспользоваться другим аккаунтом с заходом через почту, через него задал этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793449/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0). Можно ли его как-то перебросить с того аккаунта, с которого он задан на этот, с которого я сейчас пишу?

Comment: можно объединить аккаунты

Comment: @AK а как это сделать?

Comment: Самостоятельно - никак, но вы можете с обоих аккаунтов написать Николасу, управляющему сообществом. Модераторы не имеют подобных инструментов, у него - есть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв! Объединил учетные записи. (Надеюсь, с ВКонтакте проблема уже решена.)

Comment: Спасибо за объединение! Через ВК вход до сих пор осуществить не удается. С самой учетной записью ВК проблем нет. При этом вход не осуществляется только с планшета с IOS, с компьютера входит нормально. С планшета сначала выдавал ошибку «Ой, случилось страшное...», теперь пишет «There was an error fetching your account from VK. Please try logging in again».